# Docker phpMyAdmin reverse proxy using Apache - assets not loading

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy, phpmyadmin

I am running a phpMyAdmin container that I'd like to access via Apache reverse proxy. When I try to access it, it seems like the site itself is loading, i.e. the title of the page shows "phpMyAdmin" and the source of the page shows the correct HTML contents. However, the page appears totally blank as all asset links give the response `The requested URL was not found on this server.`.

[image: HTML contents]
[image: Black frontend]

I am wondering why this is happening.

My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    webserver:
        container_name: webserver
        image: php:8.2-apache
        build:
            context: ./webserver
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./public_html:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 80:80
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - app-network

    db:
        container_name: db
        image: mariadb:lts
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abc123
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - app-network

    pma:
        container_name: pma
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
            PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - app-network

volumes:
    db-data:

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
```

My site configuration `conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"    

    <Location "/phpmyadmin">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "http://pma/"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://pma/"
    </Location>    

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help with this will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!